# How do I poll a service using RXJS Observables?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, polling

Given the following code, how to I alter it to make the get request to "api/foobar" repeat every 500 milliseconds?

```
import {Observable} from "RxJS/Rx";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

@Injectable() export class ExampleService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getFooBars(onNext: (fooBars: FooBar[]) => void) {
        this.get("api/foobar")
            .map(response => <FooBar[]>reponse.json())
            .subscribe(onNext,
                   error => 
                   console.log("An error occurred when requesting api/foobar.", error));
    }
}
```

Comment: I answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42659054/2398593 and the thing is I'm not using `interval` because if your call takes more than 500ms another will be fired. My answer solves that problem :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Make sure you have imported `{Observable}` from `rxjs/Rx`. If we don't import it we get observable not found error sometimes.

Working plnkr  http://plnkr.co/edit/vMvnQW?p=preview

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
      <b>Angular 2 HTTP polling every 5 sec RxJs Observables!</b>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let doctor of doctors">{{doctor.name}}</li>
      </ul>

      `
})

export class MyApp {
  private doctors = [];
  pollingData: any;      

  constructor(http: Http) {
   this.pollingData = Observable.interval(5000)
    .switchMap(() => http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')).map((data) => data.json())
        .subscribe((data) => {
          this.doctors=data; 
           console.log(data);// see console you get output every 5 sec
        });
  }

 ngOnDestroy() {
    this.pollingData.unsubscribe();
}
}
```

Comment: How do you stop the interval? This keep going every 5 seconds and does not stop.

Comment: implement ngOnDestroy() and unsubscribe the observable on component destroy

Comment: This can be dangerous - if the requests are taking longer than 5000, the next time switchMap runs, it will cancel the previous request. Thus if all of your requests are taking longer than 5000, then each one will cancel the next, and you wont get any polling.
(5000 should be safe, but 500 would be too small)

Comment: Use `concatMap` if you're worried about requests taking too long as it will keep track of each request and process them in the correct sequence.

Comment: If you don't want to wait 5 seconds for your first data: `.interval(5000).startWith(0)`

Comment: It works well but when there is error in api, the whole interval breaks.

Comment: @ideep try to catch your error in subscribe err parameter. I forgot to add error parameter in subscribe

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
return Observable.interval(2000) 
        .switchMap(() => this.http.get(url).map(res:Response => res.json()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That seemed to me like it would work, as well. However, I get this error:  `EXCEPTION: Observable_1.Observable.interval is not a function`. I am using RxJS version 5-beta. Is it possible rolling back to version 4 would solve this?

Comment: I guess you can in the package.json file

Answer (score -4):

Why not try `setInterval(`)?

```
setInterval(getFooBars(), 500);
```

Comment: Why was this answer down voted? Readers like me would be interested in why this answer is "bad".

Comment: it was downvoted because this is a regular interval that does not use the observable pattern, whereas the question is how to use polling(interval)  mechanism with observables. Also, utilizing the setInterval method shall enforce the function getFooBars to execute and fire the API every 500 ms that cannot be cancelled whether a response has returned or not. With observables, execution of api can be cancelled when the same api is fired again.

Comment: it is a good solution if you are using angularjs, but for angular+ it is better to use an Observable approach