# How to Set an Inteval on Angular 2 Http Observable Request

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, intervals, polling

I made an Angular 2 service that successfully gets data from my server. It has one function named `getSinglePowerBlock`. The goal of this function is to setup an observable to make the `get` request to the given URL, and return one of the `powerblock` elements from the JSON property `assets.powerblock[]`. I know this works successfully, because I can get it to work in one of my components. I have included that component, for reference.

**My Goal:**
I want my code to make the `get` call continuously, once per second, using the `interval` function from the `rxjs` library. Then, I want my local data to update with the data from each poll response. Basically, a polling solution.

I imagine it's not hard to do, but I'm new to Observables and Rxjs and I just can't seem to get the syntax correct. Feel free to offer a better way to do the `getPowerBlock` function or the way I'm calling it. I'm sure you're much smarter than me at this.

**I only want the polling to be on when this component is the current page being viewed by the user.**

The Service:

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { PowerBlock } from './classes/power-block';

@Injectable()
export class ServerCommsService {

  private pbIndex: number = 0;

  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  getPowerBlock(): Observable<PowerBlock> {
    return this.http
      .get('/database-calls/getdata?type=powerblock')
      .map((r: Response) => r.json().assets.powerblock[this.pbIndex] as PowerBlock);
  }
}
```

The Component that uses the Service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable }        from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { PowerBlock } from '../classes/power-block';
import { ServerCommsService } from '../server-comms.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'power-block',
  templateUrl: 'power-block.component.html'
})
export class PowerBlockComponent implements OnInit {
  public title: string = 'PowerBlock';
  private powerBlock: PowerBlock;

  constructor(
    private server: ServerCommsService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.server.getPowerBlock().subscribe(
      pb => this.powerBlock = pb,
      err => {console.log(err)}
    );
  }
}
```

The `JSON` returned from the server:

```
{
    "assets": {
        "powerblock": [
            {
                "id": "001",
                "name": "PB1",
            },
            {
                "id": "002",
                "name": "PB2",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Do Polling with Angular 2 Observables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658162/how-to-do-polling-with-angular-2-observables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so its wise to call an interval on a returned promise/observable but if you are just returning the data (not observable/promise), you can do this inside the timer in angular2. It will continuously call the function after 1 second

```
import {OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
```

Create a subscription holder variable in your component

```
private timerSubscription: any;   //just to hold the reference
```

You can initialize the timer in your OnInit event and get the subscription back in your variable in order to unsubscribe later in OnDestroy.

```
ngOnInit()
{
    //start a timer after one second
    let timer = Observable.timer(1000, 1000);
    this.timerSubscription = timer.subscribe((t:any) => {
        //call your getPowerBlock function here 
    });
}
```

In last, just destroy the subscription as its no longer needed.

```
ngOnDestroy()
{
    if(this.timerSubscription)
        this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Is it better to do this sort of thing with an Observable or a Promise?

Comment: I don't think so its wise to do this on an observable but if you are just returning the data (not observable/promise), you can do this. It will continuously pool after 1 second

Comment: What if I only want the timer on when the component is the current page?

Comment: The timer in the component will only execute when it loads in any page, you just need to make sure you are destroying it in ngOnDestroy