# Observable polling?

Tags: angular

I currently have an Observable timer:

```
private poller(): Observable<PrepareData> {
    return Observable.timer(0, 5000).switchMap(() => this.http.get("/cgi/dashboard.php")).map(res => res.json());
}
```

I'd like to have it so a get request is done 5 seconds after the last one completed. Any easy way to do this?

Comment: btw, do you need only a single get request 5 secs after,  or do you want continuous requests every 5 secs?

Comment: Continuous requests every 5 seconds, but don't want more than one request at a time running

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an interesting question and I had some fun to come up with a solution.

This solution **wait for the previous to finish** as you expect :

```
const { Observable, Subject } = Rx

const getFakeHttpRequest$ = () => Observable.of('response !').delay(3000)

const polling$ = new Subject()

Observable
  // need to tick the first time
  .of(null)
  // everytime our polling$ subject will emit, we'll do again what's next
  .merge(polling$)
  // register to a fake request
  .switchMap(_ =>
    getFakeHttpRequest$()
      .do(_ => {
        // once we're here, the request is done
        // no mater how long it was to get a response ...
        console.log('HTTP request done !');

        // ... we wait 5s and then send a new value to polling$ subject
        // in order to trigger a new request
        setTimeout(_ => polling$.next(null), 5000)
      })
  )
  .subscribe()
```

Notice that I've put a 3s delay on the request, and that a new request kicks in every 8s, as we waited 3s for the response and then 5s as requested in your question.

Here's a working Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/kXefUbPleqyyUOlfwGuO?p=info

Comment: @Maxime You don't need to use a subject here. Check my solution.

Answer (score 11):

I'll add my answer as @Maxime's answer works, but there is actually **[no need for a subject](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx)**.

This is done using the `.concat()` operator and recursion with the `getData()` function.

> ### [`.concat()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#static-method-concat)
>
> *Concatenates multiple Observables together by sequentially emitting their values, one Observable after the other.*
>
> (...)
>
> `concat` will subscribe to first input Observable and emit all its values, without changing or affecting them in any way. When that Observable completes, it will subscribe to then next Observable passed and, again, emit its values. This will be repeated, until the operator runs out of Observables. When last input Observable completes, `concat` will complete as well.

(I used the js version in order to make a snippet that works with stack Overflow's tool, but this is the same for typescript):

```js
function someHTTPCall() {
  // well it's a fake http call
  console.log("making the Http request (can take up to 5s)...");
  return Rx.Observable.of("http response !")
    .delay(Math.round(Math.random() * 5000));
}

function getData() {
  return someHTTPCall()
    .concat(Rx.Observable.timer(5000).switchMap(() => getData()));
}

let myObs = getData();

myObs.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data,"waiting for 5 seconds before next request");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.4.0/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: and how to stop if i go to other page?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the interval operator:

```
private poller(): Observable<PrepareData> {
    return Observable.interval(5000).switchMap(() => this.http.get("/cgi/dashboard.php")).map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: Does Interval wait for the previous to finish?

Comment: don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @n00dl3's answer, I created a generic poll method that works for the web and looks if the tab is visible before it triggers of another api request.

```
function getPrice$() {
  return from(
      fetch(API_PRICE_MULTI_URL))
      .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
      })
  );
}

function poll$(pollObservableFactory, pollInterval) {
  return (document.hidden ? empty : pollObservableFactory)().pipe(
       concat(
            timer(pollInterval).pipe(
               switchMap(() => poll$(pollObservableFactory, pollInterval))
            )
       )
  );
}

// and test it like this
const sub=poll$(getPrice$, PRICE_POLL_INTERVAL).subscribe(console.log)
```

When the user has switched to another window , the poll will not make the api call.

Answer (score 0):

Posting another solution as [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42659054/2398593) is more than 6 years old and while it was an idea at the time (but not a brilliant one, I have to admit! Using intermediate variable is never good in a reactive flow!) the RxJS API has evolved since and there's now a way easier and elegant solution to achieve this:

```js
defer(() => yourRequest())
  .pipe(
    retry({ delay: 3000 }),
    repeat({ delay: 3000 })
  )
```

This will do exactly what is asked here: rerun a request X seconds after it's finished. It's also handling in the same way the error case. As soon as a request errors, it'll retry it after x seconds.

- It has no back pressure like the solution suggesting to use `interval`
- It has no intermediate variables as I had in my previous solution
- It handles the error case
- It's 5 lines long above but may as well be considered a 1 liner solution

`defer(() => yourRequest()).pipe(({ delay: 3000 }), ({ delay: 3000 }))`