# Http Service polling with observables

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5

I am trying to get polling working within Angular 2 with `Observables`. I know there are a number of other answers out there, however I cannot get them to work for me.

I know its a pure understanding thing, so an explanation of the answer (what its doing and why) and not pure code would be appreciated.

**test.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class EtlService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }

//Get ETL by status
get(): Observable<EtlByStatus> {
    var url = 'someURL';

    return this.http
        .get(url)

        .map(response => {
            return {
                headers: response.json().data.headers,
                dataSet: response.json().data.data
            }
        });
}
```

Calling this service works as expected with a simple subscribe:

```
this._service
            .get()
            .subscribe(
                res=> {
                    this.headers= res.headers;
                    this.data = res.dataSet;
});
```

However, my issue is polling. As best I can tell, polling should be done from within the `Component` to allow the service to be more reusable - the HTTP request is simple, and can be processed any number of ways.

**test.component.ts**

```
pollGet(timer: number = 30000): Observable<GetInterface> {
        return Observable.interval(timer)
            .switchMap((res) => {
                this._service.get();
            })
            .map(res => res)
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log('testing');
            })
    }
```

The above returns `res => void is not assignable` and `type void is not assignable to type ObservableInput`. I've tried turning the get line in the middle into a return, and that gives more errors and returns messages that `subscribe` is a function.

As such, how do you use `Observables` for polling? I am sure its my understanding of `map`, `switchMap` and `subscribe` and how they all play as part of an `observable` but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Observable polling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657380/observable-polling)

Comment: It is similar but the top answer does not use intervals. The second answer does, but there is no explanation around what the code is doing or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function `pollGet` is attending to return `Observable<GetInterface>`, based on reusable principle, so the **finally** subscribe is not fit here because it will turn the return type to `subscription`.

About `switchMap`:

`switchMap` is used for combining observable chain which the **Observable** in `switchMap` is based on the result of the original Observable. So here you should return type Observable in `switchMap`.

according to your code, the observable in `switchMap` are not related to any original observable results, so here you can simply using `map`.

so the final working code block would be as below:

```
pollGet(timer: number = 30000): Observable<any> {
    return Observable
               .interval(timer)
               .map(() => {
                   //return this.http.get('111');
                   // make sure your r_service.get return an Observable as the example above: http.get
                   return this._service.get();
               })
               .map(res => res);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why you use `map` twice? I am struggling to get the right context, however it is polling which is what I asked for. Thanks

Comment: @Doug the first map will create a new stream of your `_service.get` and the second `map` is based on what you want to return from `_service.get`. so you can return `response` it self or `response.data` or `response.data.xxx` in the second map.

Answer (score 0):

Your map needs to be inside the switchMap. I do believe switchMap is the correct use here because you want to return a NEW observable, not the integer that interval emits. What you need to do is attach your map to process the http/service response.

```
pollGet(timer: number = 30000): Observable<GetInterface> {
  return Observable.interval(timer)
    .switchMap((intervalCounter) => {
      return this._service.get() // note that you need a return here, or inline return
        .map(res => res);
    })
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log('testing');
    })
}
```