# Angular 4 repeating click get http observable data multiple times

Tags: angular, http, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have this service, that provides me with data from an API as an Observable.
In my component, if the user double taps the get-method, the data is pushed many times into the array. Im pretty new to the RxJs lib., but i have a feeling, that it can be fixed with the .switchMap(), using a BehaviorSubject or having the | async pipe?

The "hitsArray"-array, is what contains the data in the HTML as a ngFor - the responsedata from the http get, is being pushed into the array more than 1 time, if the user "spams" the function by repeatedly clicking.

Service:

```
  getStories(page: string, hits: string, feed: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.getToken()
      .flatMap(idToken => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.set('user_token', idToken);
        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('page', page)
        params.set('hits', hits)
        params.set('feed', feed)
        return this.http
          .get(`${this.apiUrl}/stories`, { params: params, headers: headers })
          .map((res: Response) => {
            //console.log(response);
            console.log("params: " + params);
            const data = res.json();
            return data;
          });
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

component:

```
private getStories(page, hits, feed) {
    feed = this.feed;
    this.storiesService.getStories(this.page, this.hits, this.feed)
      .subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        if (!data || data.hits == 0 || data.hits < 6) {
          this.finished = true;
          console.log("No more hits :(")
        } else {
          this.finished = false;
          for (let story of data.hits) {
            this.hitsArray.push(story);
            console.log("Feed me!")
          }
        }
      })
    console.log("side: " + this.page)
  }

  getInitialFeed(feed) {
    this.hitsArray.length = 0;
    this.page = 0;
    this.feed = feed;
    this.data = [];
    this.getStories(0, this.feed, '6');
  }

  onScroll() {
    console.log("Scrolling!")
    this.scrollStories()
  }

  private scrollStories() {
    this.page++; //SCROLLING
    if (this.page > 0) {
      console.log(this.page)
      this.getStories(this.page, this.hits, this.feed);
    }
  }
```

HTML ngFor loop:

```
<div class="col-xs col-sm col-md-4 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let story of hitsArray" (click)="getSpecificStory(story)">
```

HTML function "feed" calls:

```
  <a routerLink="/discover/curated" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="getInitialFeed('curated')">Curated</a>
  <a routerLink="/discover/trending" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="getInitialFeed('trending')">Trending</a>
  <a routerLink="/discover/latest" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="getInitialFeed('latest')">Latest</a>
```

Comment: there is no call to the `getStories` method in the provided template code.

Comment: Sorry i didn't think it'd be necessary - the function is being called by another function. I have now included that part.

Comment: to me this is more or less the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657380/observable-polling/44110016#44110016) except that you don't use a timer but a click to trigger the request. You can create a subject that handle the click, and use it instead of the `Observable.timer(5000)`

Comment: Does this answer help you ?

Comment: Im reading it and trying out some stuff atm., ill get back to you in 10 min. Thank you!

Comment: Still pushes more data into the array - just waits x number of seconds before doing it. I think the problem lies with the array, and i need to find a logical place to empty the array, without messing up more lazyloading function.

Comment: Aw I didn't understand that you needed to clear the array, sorry. You want a fresh array each time ? That's it ?

Comment: Thats what im trying to do by setting `this.hitsArray = [];`, but it doesn't clear the array if i tap quickly.

Answer (score 1):

A switchmap can only prevent a return of data **if no data has been returned yet**. Your code is completely fine and does what you tell it to do: when a user clicks, you send a data request. Your problem can easily be fixed by emptying the hitsArray `this.hitsArray = [];`

Comment: Thank you - although i actually do empty the array, upon the url params being changed, the data from my API is still being pushed to the hitsArray-array, if I spam the get-request. Am i missing something, or is there a better way to errorhandle this? I can provide the full code if needed.