# Call a function every X seconds

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there any way to fire a function every X seconds or minutes in Angular 2+?

For example, what if I want to lauch a `myService.refreshloginStatus()` function from my main `app.component` every 60 seconds?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188145/call-a-javascript-function-every-5-seconds-continuously) searching on the internet but I have no idea if it could work also for this and how to implement that in Angular...Can someone provide me a concrete usage of this in Angular?

PS: let me know in the comments if in your opinion this question could be a duplicate of the linked one and I have to remove it

Comment: That duplicate would work fine in Angular

Comment: @bugs How can I implement this in angular? Can you provide me a concrete example please?  PS: should I remove this question as duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a javascript function every 5 seconds continuously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188145/call-a-javascript-function-every-5-seconds-continuously)

Comment: You can user timer from Observable to call the service after certain interval.

Comment: basically `constructor() { setInterval(()=> { this.myFunc() }, 60000); }`

Comment: Angular uses Typescript, which is just a superset of javascript. You write plain JS in your angular files and it will work just fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const reloadInterval = 60;

timer(0, reloadInterval).pipe(
  mergeMap(_ => this.myService.myHttpCall())
).subscribe()
```

That's to answer your question. But honnestly I do not think that's a good idea to do that from a component and you should rather do that directly from your service.

Also, if you're looking for a more advanced answer you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48214782/2398593).

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted your answer as the most complete, most of that for your suggestion of doing it inside the service! It works fine! By the way, I fused your answer with @luk-alex one and @Ivaro18 comment above so the (working) result I obtained is: `constructor() { setInterval(()=> { this.myFunc() }, 60000); }` inside my service! Your answer works fine too, but I've prefered to use a more simple code!

Answer (score 21):

You can use `setInterval()` function

```
setInterval(()=> { this.myFunc() }, timeIntevalSeconds * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var intervalPromise;
$scope.startTimer = function(fn, delay) {
    intervalPromise = $interval(function() {
        fn();                  
    }, delay);
};

$scope.startTimer(hello, 2000);

hello(){
  console.log("hello");
}
```