# Angular & Typescript - Issue while deactivating other users from the Admin login

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, authentication

In my web application, when I login as '**Admin**', I will be able to view, **activate**, delete etc. the user profiles of my application. 
When admin activates an user profile, the user will be able to access the application. 
When Admin deactivates an user profile, the user will not be able to access the application. 
The problem arises in the following scenario. I am logged in as some ACTIVATED user XYZ in one browser (say IE). I am logged in as ADMIN in another browser (say Chrome). Now, I am deactivating that activated user.

My **expected behavior** is, XYZ which is open in another browser should be logged out and be redirected to the Login page for a fresh sign-in. But right now, what happens is, even after deactivating XYZ, that session is in login state only.

I have tried n-number of ways to solve this issue but of no gain.
Since my code is  too long, here is the snippet of code that deals with this issue.

HTML:

```
<tbody *ngIf = "users">
<tr *ngFor = "let user of users; trackBy: trackIdentity">
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="setActive(user, true)" *ngIf="!user.activated">Deactivated</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" (click)="setActive(user, false)" *ngIf="user.activated" [disabled]="currentAccount.login === user.login">Activated</button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Component.ts:

```
setActive(user, isActivated) {
user.activated = isActivated;
this.userService.update(user).subscribe(
(response) => {
if(response.status === 200) {
    this.error = null;
    this.success = 'OK';
    this.loadAll();
    }
else {
    this.success = null;
    this.error = 'ERROR';
    }
}}
```

Suggestions and code snippets that could possibly solve my issue are most welcome.
**Workarounds in `jQuery` and `Javascript` are also welcome!**

Comment: Which authentication type, which jhipster version?

Comment: Client side are you checking periodically if the user is activated or their token is valid? If you deactivate an account how does their computer know? Some good ways to let their computer know is SignalR or long polling. You could also check their token/account every time they go to a page through an auth guard and kick them on redirect.

Comment: @TrystanHumann , if the user is deactivated, they will not be able to  login at all

Comment: @GaëlMarziou jhipster v4.14.1

Comment: Right, but how do you tell their client to log them off? I typically verify their identity/tokens on actions or redirect. If you want them off the page immediately you would need something more heavy handed like SignalR to message their client to check for permissions and log them off.

Just saw you were using jhipster. Never used it, sorry.

Comment: @TrystanHumann what you are saying is indeed a great idea. But before that, as an admin, when I deactivate an user (who is logged in in another browser), he should be logged out and redirected to login page automatically. That connection, whereby I can control an user session as an admin is what I require

Comment: I don't know much about jhipster, so I can't give you an answer using it. A simple way to implement what you are saying is to use a polling observable like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658162/how-to-do-polling-with-angular-2-observables.
They will be pinging their auth credentials, so when you deactivate their account, next time they try to verify their account it will boot them.

Comment: @TrystanHumann, Jhipster is just Angular+SpringBoot. You can solve this even without the knowledge of jhipster.

Comment: Can you post your code on how user's verify their tokens? I will do an answer post if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you selected JWT authentication type, there's no session.

Until his/her token expires, authenticated user will stay authenticated and authorized.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. The authentication I had chosen was JWT, ofcourse!

Comment: What should I do to invalidate the session as soon as the user is deactivated?

Comment: You can't because there's no session in JWT. Either you add a session mechanism server side as custom code, or you switch to another authentication type.

Comment: If that is the case, will changing the authentication type yield the desired outcome ?

Comment: Monolith or microservices?

Comment: Simpler is to use session-based auth. edit your `.yo-rc.json` file, re-generate with `jhipster --with-entities` or better idea, test first in a new project because it's been long time since I used this auth type.

Comment: how do I solve this same problem if the authentication type is session ?