# Angular observable doesn't catch new values from flask server

Tags: angular, angular7, rxjs6

My problem is that I want to read data from a server as it comes in an angular application without reloading the page.
I have a simple flask server that sends data in python:

```
from threading import Timer
from flask import Flask
import time
import random
from datetime import datetime
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

string = ''
humidity = 60
stress = 1
temperature = 20

def update_data(interval):
    Timer(interval, update_data, [interval]).start()

    global string
    global humidity
    global stress
    global temperature

    string = ''
    string += f'{{"ID":"90A2DA10F2E4",'
    string += f'"timestamp":"{datetime.now().isoformat()}",'
    string += f'"temperature":{temperature},'
    string += f'"humidity":{humidity},'
    string += f'"stress":{stress}}}\n'


    humidity = round( (humidity + (random.random()*2-1)), 2)
    stress = round( (stress + (random.random()*0.2-0.1)), 2)
    temperature = round( (temperature + (random.random()*0.2-0.1)), 2)

# update data every second
update_data(1)

@app.route("/")
@cross_origin()
def index():
    return string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And a component in angular that creates a subscription to that stream:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'prototype';
  darkTheme =  new FormControl(false);
  list = [];

  constructor(private streamService: TestDataService,
              private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.privateServer();
  }

  privateServer() {
    console.log("private server");
    console.log(this.http.get('http://localhost:5000'));
    this.http.get('http://localhost:5000').subscribe( data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.list.push(data);
    })
  }

  onClick(){
    console.log(this.list);
  }
}
```

It will be part of a service, but for testing purposes I'm trying to get it to work inside the component.
The template consist of just a button that calls onClick().
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the issue exactly ?

Comment: The issue is that after it gets the first request it doesn't get the newer data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular, request methods of `HttpClient` are intended to `complete` once the Observable produces a value. So, once the subscription callback is fired, the observable is finished (will not fire anymore).

To achieve what you ask, you either need **Polling** the data or **Web Sockets**, based on your needs.

---

For Web Sockets:

https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1

https://medium.com/factory-mind/angular-websocket-node-31f421c753ff

---

For polling:

https://nehalist.io/polling-in-angular/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41658823/1331040

Comment: Thank you, web sockets seem to be exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad to help :) I added two more links.