# Query a web api periodically with Angular observable and subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a Launch method, which takes some parameters and launches an engine.
When the engine starts, it returns the instance name.
With this instance name, I want to query another service periodically, say every 2 seconds to know if the status changed to "Succeeded" or "Failed"
I did a do while loop inside the first subscription, but it is not working as expected.

```
instanceStatus: string = "Initialized";
instanceName:string = "InstanceName";


Launch(sessionId: string, projectName: string, f: string[]) {
    this.service.Launch(sessionId, projectName, this.f)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        instanceName => {
          localStorage.setItem('instanceName', instanceName);
          this.instanceName = instanceName;
          setTimeout(() => {
            do {
              this.service.getEngineStatus(this.instanceName)
                .pipe(first())
                .subscribe(
                  status => {
                    this.instanceStatus = status;
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(this.instanceStatus);
                    this.loadingService.showSpinner({ text: 'Modeling is running...' });
                    if (this.instanceStatus === "Succeeded") {
                      this.messageService.add({ severity: Severity.Success, summary: 'Fault modeling completed', detail: 'Via MessageService' });
                      this.messageService.clear();
                    }
                  }
                );
            } while (this.instanceStatus !== "Succeeded")
          }, 2000);
        }
      );
  }



 getEngineStatus(instanceName:string): Observable<string> {
    this.serviceUrl = URL + `?instance=` + instanceName;
    return this._http.get<string>(this.serviceUrl);
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Do Polling with Angular 2 Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658162/how-to-do-polling-with-angular-2-observables)

Comment: Thanks Liam, but it is outdated. 'interval' property does not exist on Observable anymore.

Comment: It does exist, it's just created differently since later versions of rxjs https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/interval

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [`interval` creation operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/interval)? I believe this might be what you need to use. I gave it a shot using this operator and the code looks like this:

```
Launch(sessionId: string, projectName: string, f: string[]) {
  this.service
    .Launch(sessionId, projectName, this.f)
    .pipe(
      first(),
      tap((instanceName) => {
        localStorage.setItem('instanceName', instanceName);
        this.instanceName = instanceName;
      }),
      switchMap(() => interval(2000)),
      takeWhile(() => !['Succeeded', 'Failed'].contains(this.instanceStatus)),
      tap(() => {
        this.loadingService.showSpinner({
          text: 'Modeling is running...',
        });
      }),
      switchMap(() => this.service.getEngineStatus(this.instanceName))
    )
    .subscribe((status) => {
      this.instanceStatus = status;
      this.loadingService.hideSpinner();
      console.log(status);
      console.log(this.instanceStatus);

      if (this.instanceStatus === 'Succeeded') {
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: Severity.Success,
          summary: 'Fault modeling completed',
          detail: 'Via MessageService',
        });
        this.messageService.clear();
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I have tried this, but it is not even querying the second service. I also did that change !['Succeeded', 'Failed'].includes(this.instanceStatus)),

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid nested subscriptions. Instead try to use higher order mapping operators like `switchMap`.
2. Instead of using JS statements like `for` or `while`, using RxJS functions like `interval` or `timer` for polling.
3. Use `tap` operator to do side effects like pushing data to local storage.

```js
import { Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, finalize, switchMap, takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

POLL_INTERVAL = 2000;
instanceStatus: string = "Initialized";
instanceName:string = "InstanceName";

this.Launch(sample, sample, sample).pipe(
  switchMap((instanceName: any) => 
    timer(0, POLL_INTERVAL).pipe(                                         // <-- start immediately and poll every 'n' secs
      switchMap(() => this.service.getEngineStatus(instanceName)),
      takeWhile((instanceStatus: any) => instanceStatus === 'Succeeded'), // <-- stop poll when status !== 'Succeeded'
      finalize(() => {                                                    // <-- run when polling stops
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: Severity.Success,
          summary: 'Fault modeling completed',
          detail: 'Via MessageService'
        });
        this.messageService.clear();
      })
    )
  ).subscribe({
    next: (instanceStatus: any) => this.instanceStatus = instanceStatus
  });
)

Launch(sessionId: string, projectName: string, f: string[]): Observable<any> {
  return this.service.Launch(sessionId, projectName, this.f).pipe(
    first(),
    tap((instanceName: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('instanceName', instanceName);
      this.instanceName = instanceName;
    })
  );
}
```

Update (Thanks to @Liam):

1. `do` is now `tap` operator.
2. The `.subscribe()` must be at the last level after the `pipe()` function. It was erroneously inside it. Please try the code again.

Comment: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(project: (value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>): OperatorFunction<string, any>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(instanceName: string) => Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
      Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.

Comment: Overload 3 of 3, '(project: (value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>, resultSelector: (outerValue: string, innerValue: any, outerIndex: number, innerIndex: number) => unknown): OperatorFunction<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(instanceName: string) => Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
      Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'

Comment: It seems like you're trying to assign a subscription to an observable. Please show the full code you're trying. Also please update it in your original question and in this comment section.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have tried your code, and got the following errors.

Comment: getEngineStatus(instanceName:string): Observable<string> {
    this.serviceUrl= URL + `?instance=` + instanceName;
    return this._http.get<string>(this.serviceUrl);
  }

Comment: added the complementary code getEngineStatus

Comment: @Liam: Thanks, I quite overlooked the `do`/`tap` operator while writing the answer. And the `subscription` is a result of not checking the answer before posting it. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, from what I can see, that something like this would be part of the way toward an answer for you.

The key here is that the timer emits a value every 2 seconds while `status !== "Succeeded"`. Once `status === "Succeeded"` the `true` for the second argument in `takeWhile` will allow the final emission before it closes the timer (No more checks every 2 seconds).

The rest follows from that.

```ts
launch(sessionId: string, projectName: string, f: string[]): void {
  this.service.launch(sessionId, projectName, f).pipe(

    first(),
    tap(instanceName => {
      localStorage.setItem('instanceName', instanceName);
      this.instanceName = instanceName;
    }),
    switchMap((instanceName:string) => timer(0,2000).pipe(
      exhaustMap(_ => this.service.getEngineStatus(instanceName).pipe(
        first()
      )),
      takeWhile((status:string) => status !== "Succeeded", true),
      map(status => ({instanceName, status}))
    ))

  ).subscribe(({instanceName, status}) => {
    this.loadingService.showSpinner({ text: 'Modeling is running...' });
    if (status === "Succeeded") {
      this.messageService.add({ 
        severity: Severity.Success, 
        summary: 'Fault modeling completed', 
        detail: 'Via MessageService' 
      });
      this.messageService.clear();
    }
  });
}
```

---

#### Update

Here is some code that does what you're after but is entirely self-contained. This isn't based on your code (since I can't run/test code I don't have access to).

The timers in the service simulate some delay between requesting and receiving a response.

```ts
type Status = "Succeeded" | "Other"

interface Service {
  // We'll pretend we can't query privateStatus directly, for example
  // it could be data on a server that you can only access via getStatus
  privateStatus: Status,
  launch: (sessionId: string) => Observable<string>,
  getStatus: (instanceName: string) => Observable<Status>
}

class ArbiratryClass {

  service: Service;
  readonly PING_INTERVAL = 2000; 

  constructor(){
    this.service = {
      privateStatus: "Other",
      launch: (sessionId: string) => timer(8000).pipe(
        mapTo(""),
        tap(status => this.service.privateStatus = "Succeeded"),
        filter(_ => false),
        startWith(`Hello ${sessionId}`)
      ),
      getStatus: _ => timer(500).pipe(mapTo(this.service.privateStatus))
    }
  }

  arbiratryInit(sessionId: string) {

    // Launch session, then query the status every ping_Interval 
    // and print the result to the console.
    this.service.launch(sessionId).pipe(
      switchMap(instanceName => timer(0,this.PING_INTERVAL).pipe(
        exhaustMap(_ => this.service.getStatus(instanceName)),
        takeWhile(status => status !== "Succeeded", true),
        map(status => ({instanceName, status}))
      ))
    ).subscribe(console.log);

  }
  
}

new ArbiratryClass().arbiratryInit("ABCD_1234");
```

The output to the console when I run this:

```html
{ instanceName: 'Hello ABCD_1234', status: 'Other' }
{ instanceName: 'Hello ABCD_1234', status: 'Other' }
{ instanceName: 'Hello ABCD_1234', status: 'Other' }
{ instanceName: 'Hello ABCD_1234', status: 'Other' }
{ instanceName: 'Hello ABCD_1234', status: 'Succeeded' }
```

Comment: getEngineStatus never gets queried. The debugger does not enter switchMap

Comment: @TropicalViking For obvious reasons, I can't really debug your code. I don't have access so I have no way of knowing why what you're attempting doesn't work. Maybe I made a typo? Maybe you're code has an error elsewhere? No idea. What I've done is to create a working example. You can see that in an update to my answer.